# My approach to the fair rations problem in hackerrank gets 11 failed testcases out of 23. What is wrong?

Tags: python

link to the problem - https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/fair-rations/problem

my approach is by considering sub-arrays within the list with the first and last elements as odd numbers with even numbers between them. The no of loaves required to make the sub-array even is twice the difference of the indexes of the odd numbers.

here is my approach -

```
a=input()

b=list(map(int,input().split()))

def ec_odd(li):
count=0
for i in li:
    if i%2==1:
        count+=1
if count%2==0:
    return True
else:
    return False

idx_li=[]

loaves=0

if ec_odd(b):
for i in b:
    if i%2==1:
        c=b.index(i)
        idx_li.append(c)

length=len(idx_li)

j=0

while j<=length-1:
    s1=idx_li[j]
    s2=idx_li[j+1]

    loaves+=2*(s2-s1)
    j+=2

print(loaves)

else:
print('NO')
```

Comment: Please format you code correctly, to enable others to read it properly, so they'll be able to help you

Answer (score 0):

O(n) in python by counting the number of flips between pairs of odd numbers

used modulo as boolean even%2 is equivalent to False and odd%2 is True

```
total = 0
a = None
flips = 0
for i in range(len(arr)):
    if arr[i]%2 and a == None:
        total += 1
        a = i
    elif arr[i]%2:
        total += 1
        flips += i - a
        a = None             
return 'NO' if total%2 else flips * 2
```